# Postgres Timestamp to DATE dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

im trying to insert select a casted timestamp in a date colum timestamp like 02-09-2021 00:00:00, and i need to convert this timestamp to date dd-mm-yyyy without hhmmss, i've tried select date(column) as newdate but when i check my table insert, it keeps like timestamp, all the solutions that i tried only runs perfectly only in a select sentence, but when i try to insert select.. i keep with timestamp type..

Comment: A SELECT won't change the content or the data type of a column. If you want to change the column from `timestamp` to `date` your need to `ALTER` the table.

Comment: Change the data to a valid timestamp (the datatype that is) before you insert the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to convert formatted text to `timestamp` then use `to_timestamp` with explicit format specification. Try this:

```sql
select to_timestamp('02-09-2021 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

| to_timestamp |
| --- |
| 2021-02-09 00:00:00.000 +0200 |

To convert it to `date`:

```sql
select to_date('02-09-2021 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy');
```

If you need to change the type of an existing `timestamp` column to `date` then:

```sql
alter table the_table alter column the_column type date using the_column::date;
```

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: Will you post the DDL of your table(s) please? Where does `02-09-2021 00:00:00` come from, another table? It looks like formatted text. Please note that dates and timestamps do not have format. They can only be _presented_ in different formats.